# In the generalized Bezout's identity, is the variable term t always infinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If the equation $ey +fz = gcd(e,f)$ has a solution $(y_0,z_0)$, then all the infinitely many integer solutions to the equation are given by $y = rt+y_0$,  $z = st+z_0$, where $r = f/gcd(e,f)$ and $s = −e/gcd(e,f)$.

This is the generalized Bezout Identity and can be found on page 5 of H. Rose, *A course in number theory*.

Since t is a variable term, and since the generalized Bezout's identity has infinitely many solutions, does it mean that can $t$ always take infinitely many values? I guess I am trying  to ask if there is ever a situation where t takes only finite number of integers.

My hunch tells me that t is always infinite in the generalized Bezout's identity and therefore any integer in the number line can be inserted in the place of t and will satisfy the generalized Bezout's identity.

The motivation for this question is that I was working on generalized Bezout's identity of a certain pair of integers and my calculations led to the implication that t takes on only a finite number of values. I suspect my calculation is wrong.

Comment: Nice first question!

Comment: If you could type your calculation in here, then someone would be able to point at exactly *what* is wrong in it.

Comment: the set of integer pairs with $ey+fz=0$  is called a lattice. It has infinitely many  points, those being evenly spaced dots on the same line